# Understanding why I get an error in computations when removing certain columns gives zero error: library(lpSolve)

Tags: r

I understand that this question has been asked before but I could not solve the question with the current solutions after searching.

I am running into an error:

```
Error in solve.default(covs) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.08804e-18
```

Code: (which give the error)

```
library(lpSolve)
  retbar <- colMeans(rets, na.rm = T)
  covs <- var(rets, na.rm = T) # calculates the covariance
  invS <- solve(covs)
```

Other:

```
> det(covs)
[1] 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003458185

> qr(covs)$rank
[1] 20
```

However when I remove some variables and run the code it works....

Code2: (which works)

```
rets$B6 <- NULL
rets$M6 <- NULL
rets$R6 <- NULL
rets$Q6 <- NULL

  retbar <- colMeans(rets, na.rm = T)
  covs <- var(rets, na.rm = T) # calculates the covariance
  invS <- solve(covs)

> det(covs)
[1] 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003514001

    > qr(covs)$rank
    [1] 20
```

I just want to understand why removing "X6" variable from my data allows me to solve the cov matrix. I have seen that "X6" (X here is B,M,R,Q) is correlated with other variables - "X6" is calculated as "X5 - X1" (or: B5 -B1, M5 - M1, R-5 - R1, Q5 - Q1") - I would like to idealy keep all columns in the data.

Data:

EDIT: New df

```
rets <- structure(list(B1 = c(0.0201596769556875, 0.00796992085297743, 
0.0492147329548896, 0.019344865533839, 0.0215214485329025, 0.0207218693128776, 
0.0103862072924815, 0.0140747415980048, 0.0261785500777131, 0.0373946762995772, 
-0.00684759663692184, -0.0524902194742576, 0.00315800118629925, 
0.0311087399558667, 0.0296245772665513, -0.0714423815378389, 
-0.00828133058937649, -0.0474562526488911, -0.027177578320533, 
-0.0150494495620104, 0.0348119470955449, 0.026557944400082, -0.0948970420281616, 
0.020249494359762, 0.0362642768918328, -0.108930302464037, -0.209399350620045, 
-0.131078973014079, 0.0340021699340833, -0.0392411420552388, 
-0.104669817843903, 0.126868769506696, 0.180232948671053, 0.0769264211043898, 
0.019176729939273, 0.0993469049194573, 0.0738823618605167, 0.0686517377053094, 
-0.0438445535170806, 0.0291731714634921, 0.074704119945333, -0.00156713313391479, 
0.041919134266091, 0.0718713711298, 0.0616824041447802, -0.0694331912797978, 
-0.0664994905875237, -0.0637350113576239, 0.0995459645599069, 
0.0350470019423567), B2 = c(0.0159402689787551, 0.0162507344633192, 
0.0740337591014227, 0.0384769820770539, 0.0091777285515574, 0.0266077913225889, 
0.0135757617808849, 0.00407485086602279, 0.024561373325238, 0.0369076019690258, 
-0.0111998096779211, -0.0550216348217377, 0.00296776607315141, 
0.0155911183644963, 0.0127829585460845, -0.0686988206697129, 
-0.0120169929067047, -0.0379441518196964, -0.00997556953482333, 
-0.0157591765829324, 0.0259378688367708, 0.0348720134553493, 
-0.0864851422178537, 0.0243151482365286, 0.054450975569433, -0.105384283400191, 
-0.244132080369671, -0.149214851674911, 0.0642730083371614, -0.0732165541787947, 
-0.132146613068358, 0.117037257468365, 0.243486361548774, 0.127689400206569, 
0.0507680353897798, 0.0918127231182545, 0.057623460462537, 0.0664555639592365, 
-0.0637209916042463, 0.0351111011481844, 0.0774253568342104, 
-0.0208447613007578, 0.0464411219167523, 0.088343873921378, 0.0845804848931461, 
-0.0672340736611374, -0.063074008563108, -0.0552850698211716, 
0.118020745550881, 0.0350453682926441), B3 = c(0.0254691625247841, 
0.0122239330016886, 0.0446599436180717, 0.0289436320423226, 0.00984126934358344, 
0.0248495851877287, 0.0070023062540998, 0.00867717868910234, 
0.0198468884639984, 0.0423526987264829, -0.00673483175868612, 
-0.0536716292198917, 0.00702602564601019, 0.0161515106339872, 
0.00881414723751897, -0.0704128768108256, -0.0118703057246587, 
-0.0654796158401091, -0.0214858440189339, -0.0287089650155394, 
0.0375015423973781, 0.0669904486938052, -0.0941557378605896, 
0.0153425838301645, 0.0209397917472626, -0.101627763946357, -0.226324878317675, 
-0.141233587277128, 0.0562599340844954, -0.0426624056954274, 
-0.101409613365061, 0.095072163016385, 0.19560509325657, 0.153377825232805, 
0.0250685160313996, 0.0912032732747058, 0.0514030426458047, 0.0803912808233686, 
-0.0604690113263003, 0.0268422517753881, 0.10412185199629, -0.0227046178907074, 
0.045247514742643, 0.080985450832222, 0.0646318077059794, -0.0703469469216747, 
-0.0487479424020042, -0.0677789445266782, 0.102936536920121, 
0.0372798264656416), B4 = c(0.0219191738217161, 0.0176853257846887, 
0.0456353457446462, 0.0341367113786865, 0.0224113039756616, 0.0198275955536373, 
0.00679047712618314, 0.00326894704835364, 0.0279149805055439, 
0.0270857608217435, -0.00413393714898988, -0.0566739462091404, 
-0.0114439339594225, 0.011077534748248, 0.0166466370578447, -0.0733647442632695, 
-0.0100085083715353, -0.0525145185232886, -0.0326582904953551, 
-0.0193272575954162, 0.028187178228298, 0.037490075562138, -0.0740065271333753, 
0.0376882236271473, 0.0170308927355229, -0.0991359056176541, 
-0.224423397219161, -0.118318357393019, 0.0765578429241032, -0.0580225262433487, 
-0.110441975119102, 0.101623526281797, 0.208245933500372, 0.0931300452658907, 
0.0371493076663389, 0.109834174058939, 0.0451845252205385, 0.0922986324245771, 
-0.0604417879228685, 0.0176772270368012, 0.0760699055274017, 
-0.0219431067610276, 0.0363180693269241, 0.10978144288715, 0.0703026600940392, 
-0.0827017008478804, -0.0577866241297221, -0.0682246277864018, 
0.112824937430707, 0.042166109959073), B5 = c(0.0393541248460465, 
0.00956169994553254, 0.045506941231113, 0.022679161458704, 0.0071175687346599, 
0.0245724846722118, -0.00486326015007488, 0.00977777199018314, 
0.0372227348807343, 0.0421686696514302, -0.00729705359364536, 
-0.0420398232585704, -0.00198560837531052, 0.0191012049979939, 
0.0151182378767174, -0.0720890664222317, -0.0145999296151926, 
-0.0549852597740717, -0.0357418224487, -0.00858510372461121, 
0.0371052230990963, 0.0358706764622103, -0.0797211143737148, 
0.0133179042163717, 0.0227502855968991, -0.0960364954219236, 
-0.20877985810845, -0.125247884467955, 0.0582827803341161, -0.0546479539249937, 
-0.127419512889315, 0.161520030974712, 0.213080660094016, 0.108923963868525, 
0.0216324723000225, 0.123493437786137, 0.0643989332634697, 0.065803254107272, 
-0.0624072744596408, 0.0370168039973202, 0.0836690142031841, 
-0.0128692586306809, 0.0506633041324735, 0.0963571736706436, 
0.0704426407884252, -0.0733420360542838, -0.0710357171347283, 
-0.0688377671567964, 0.132571567141589, 0.0447762558807919), 
    B6 = c(0.019194447890359, 0.00159177909255511, -0.0037077917237766, 
    0.00333429592486495, -0.0144038797982426, 0.00385061535933419, 
    -0.0152494674425564, -0.00429696960782166, 0.0110441848030212, 
    0.00477399335185296, -0.000449456956723525, 0.0104503962156872, 
    -0.00514360956160977, -0.0120075349578728, -0.0145063393898339, 
    -0.00064668488439279, -0.00631859902581606, -0.00752900712518056, 
    -0.00856424412816701, 0.00646434583739916, 0.00229327600355132, 
    0.00931273206212835, 0.0151759276544468, -0.00693159014339035, 
    -0.0135139912949337, 0.0128938070421132, 0.000619492511594932, 
    0.00583108854612438, 0.0242806104000329, -0.0154068118697549, 
    -0.0227496950454118, 0.0346512614680161, 0.0328477114229624, 
    0.0319975427641352, 0.00245574236074952, 0.0241465328666802, 
    -0.00948342859704696, -0.00284848359803735, -0.0185627209425603, 
    0.0078436325338281, 0.00896489425785109, -0.0113021254967661, 
    0.00874416986638248, 0.0244858025408436, 0.008760236643645, 
    -0.00390884477448601, -0.00453622654720459, -0.00510275579917252, 
    0.0330256025816826, 0.00972925393843514), M1 = c(0.0113396747037768, 
    -0.036155735142529, 0.0550687853246927, 0.0269238017499447, 
    0.00982287898659706, 0.00809061527252197, -0.047512024641037, 
    -0.016009446233511, -0.00278357416391373, -0.00628054095432162, 
    -0.0609199032187462, -0.0494923722396639, 0.00698078286246139, 
    0.00983662394804645, 0.0380059639114982, -0.0652908706460783, 
    -0.00563693966137906, -0.0491752210641838, -0.0214304637710383, 
    -0.0153438172807354, 0.0203537379326515, 0.0421207453446271, 
    -0.083814601712769, 0.0152837951106913, 0.031787003709805, 
    -0.107241585677281, -0.210874717399826, -0.115555851834153, 
    0.0599437241751638, -0.0587498251989018, -0.0995314111424103, 
    0.104148721637336, 0.182319135902193, 0.105787461175244, 
    0.033689877375748, 0.0966363048202885, 0.0640538126301515, 
    0.0640782744095522, -0.0440799278693556, 0.0303018999590801, 
    0.0841023643583563, -0.0176897923202359, 0.0382914170044418, 
    0.0759079900327234, 0.0738894489211014, -0.0566797658200011, 
    -0.0592523659979936, -0.0605415574124922, 0.108837738508142, 
    0.0311480459267166), M2 = c(0, 0.0369318500161171, 0.05479446798563, 
    0.0441558659076691, 0.0063580423593521, -0.0073090447112918, 
    -0.0191763313487172, -0.00646415911614895, 0.0458552502095698, 
    0.0275424104183912, -0.0487805381417274, -0.0400584393734526, 
    -0.00416827541765468, 0.0212708574224962, 0.0174144436427715, 
    -0.0674113624348997, -0.0125841060695098, -0.0558416555270291, 
    -0.0163345211185515, -0.0219548647100168, 0.0504916901610439, 
    0.0417230815077788, -0.0769711063634779, 0.0167976787218786, 
    0.0430265647426742, -0.123826423650743, -0.234415110641567, 
    -0.130708167875127, 0.0554669174895657, -0.0450817684669273, 
    -0.12032524188012, 0.154298987141929, 0.236011380184834, 
    0.114111615690755, 0.0275421794934158, 0.0938332458107501, 
    0.0953365754115465, 0.0847282442055681, -0.0712375521873279, 
    0.0174096324909712, 0.0755245202122583, -0.00762107035320276, 
    0.0428905926947967, 0.0972422302671232, 0.076027299598966, 
    -0.0788738990751014, -0.0621384863719475, -0.0624743295694587, 
    0.116711918883773, 0.0476898780038488), M3 = c(0.0359311569482088, 
    -0.139999955892563, 0.0209301561117172, 0.104783609509468, 
    -0.0721649304032326, 0.397777765989304, -0.0111288027837873, 
    0.00482318503782153, 0.14879997074604, 0.16648281365633, 
    -0.0580596011132003, -0.047679182583228, 0.0114269531841602, 
    0.0317433578864438, 0.00775221147687179, -0.061602244912588, 
    -0.0158776681251565, -0.0648263710640019, -0.0240124892502704, 
    -0.0177448932428571, 0.0379559719894449, 0.0344511040566261, 
    -0.0775795445422815, 0.027065822418437, 0.0251577377516715, 
    -0.108475149947571, -0.235411574529894, -0.144522154940724, 
    0.0449754514928253, -0.0489695645129837, -0.123624581783743, 
    0.11508095146038, 0.211242172822533, 0.145198421859061, 0.0179784820325099, 
    0.0982173541566308, 0.0555486086463638, 0.0736606557016785, 
    -0.0583725513432673, 0.0363466235082538, 0.0690110039168571, 
    -0.0160342605855651, 0.0540222033909931, 0.0862467848463471, 
    0.0633677104077289, -0.0850614424954192, -0.0535852042349274, 
    -0.0603007163253751, 0.113070077846931, 0.0408424520012463
    ), M4 = c(-0.155844137072563, -0.0610789265483618, 0.0988630047067999, 
    -0.0086556291207671, 0.0815064907073975, -0.0185706592164934, 
    -0.0207591075450184, 0.105547562241554, -0.107201084494591, 
    0.0113929212093353, -0.022529099136591, -0.0441186886312525, 
    0.00195441980877977, 0.016870060442579, 0.00759373951839394, 
    -0.0769912599379698, -0.0171198804233096, -0.0417608516722064, 
    -0.0238246997368977, -0.0177104066632295, 0.0235756050630395, 
    0.0269268993848493, -0.0967296211775303, 0.0324606583258286, 
    0.0290416693746976, -0.092120191410525, -0.230766838669409, 
    -0.140616977306715, 0.0699212552919189, -0.0613821172279649, 
    -0.129080012361016, 0.115632295353163, 0.241743159430643, 
    0.0945421887374065, 0.0330785879111653, 0.114030935722985, 
    0.0394783260686381, 0.0637947810755577, -0.060909434465672, 
    0.0323739642311314, 0.0841339563067396, -0.0184345132038895, 
    0.0495400154798214, 0.0976821368464078, 0.0614972022290451, 
    -0.0706658855287132, -0.070385725555342, -0.073441507572736, 
    0.109315224489104, 0.0374856931309638), M5 = c(-0.12346476316452, 
    -0.0105703119188547, 0.092919297516346, 0.136621922254562, 
    -0.0155999753624201, 0.0682649463415146, -0.0922404378652573, 
    0.0620875768363475, -0.0615064632147553, 0.143709745258093, 
    0.0756230279803276, -0.0617075127175431, -0.00360911323150503, 
    0.0112366336242249, 0.0154406559539872, -0.0787746054515343, 
    -0.00269523979941826, -0.0526490888305032, -0.0326128715360069, 
    -0.0167875265945536, 0.0288873225335168, 0.0437001503452364, 
    -0.0850432923719407, 0.0182440995488183, 0.0238926558011993, 
    -0.0957959717629556, -0.215013577753659, -0.144644269534711, 
    0.0501889619753152, -0.05768291939606, -0.128211720987334, 
    0.127069415092379, 0.216602876296358, 0.113530188173674, 
    0.0468711288658715, 0.122424450357045, 0.0374143540121529, 
    0.0871767761121666, -0.0567737247714127, 0.0360353329323981, 
    0.103461599696569, -0.0225164942232245, 0.0415910101081693, 
    0.0918531230749919, 0.0755528541988306, -0.0728917148203065, 
    -0.0657610368590244, -0.0564028779478209, 0.122215778161083, 
    0.045920382671152), M6 = c(-0.134804437868297, 0.0255854232236743, 
    0.0378505121916533, 0.109698120504617, -0.0254228543490172, 
    0.0601743310689926, -0.0447284132242203, 0.0780970230698586, 
    -0.0587228890508416, 0.149990286212415, 0.136542931199074, 
    -0.0122151404778793, -0.0105898960939664, 0.00140000967617841, 
    -0.0225653079575109, -0.0134837348054559, 0.00294169986196079, 
    -0.00347386776631942, -0.0111824077649687, -0.00144370931381818, 
    0.00853358460086529, 0.00157940500060929, -0.00122869065917164, 
    0.00296030443812702, -0.0078943479086057, 0.011445613914325, 
    -0.00413886035383279, -0.0290884177005585, -0.00975476219984855, 
    0.00106690580284179, -0.0286803098449235, 0.0229206934550435, 
    0.0342837403941652, 0.00774272699843015, 0.0131812514901235, 
    0.0257881455367569, -0.0266394586179985, 0.0230985017026144, 
    -0.0126937969020571, 0.00573343297331802, 0.0193592353382127, 
    -0.00482670190298854, 0.00329959310372758, 0.0159451330422685, 
    0.00166340527772912, -0.0162119490003055, -0.0065086708610308, 
    0.00413867946467136, 0.0133780396529413, 0.0147723367444354
    ), Q1 = c(0.0265621797051281, 0.0121992440563654, 0.0340947461024625, 
    0.0114726169959482, 0.0244721697934678, 0.0304556573852703, 
    -0.00256444356341105, 0.00372350399549636, 0.0237739984235116, 
    0.0270033285140239, -0.00704723803210073, -0.0476901397804718, 
    0.0071129609034004, 0.0323939519651734, 0.00323882454019589, 
    -0.0622794850397196, -0.0119234506451499, -0.0399236912960561, 
    -0.0436079844051925, -0.0261022150048638, 0.0291371183325865, 
    0.0563959058031636, -0.0907071155080928, 0.013374178530945, 
    0.0681693173169967, -0.0880869802416643, -0.218258767247561, 
    -0.138316280509299, 0.0411314660955931, -0.066409005195869, 
    -0.139430000425292, 0.101716784591166, 0.199285888061083, 
    0.0893195469347605, 0.0207835902897264, 0.0819590143972909, 
    0.0428754482336569, 0.0804621560497635, -0.0576983031786784, 
    0.026600132264742, 0.0760024661290204, -0.0281950326994129, 
    0.0424528139477703, 0.0865725399565793, 0.077255839460645, 
    -0.0690729842646359, -0.0617721764311835, -0.0619110102090971, 
    0.0975149637737052, 0.0422298654882387), Q2 = c(0.0265492763632932, 
    0.0222894305734672, 0.0476030515586719, 0.0257378459646134, 
    0.0255000609197377, 0.0300794550319551, 0.0133745468006092, 
    0.0187672452778894, 0.0248004048250247, 0.0205707288256205, 
    -0.00587681182154011, -0.0630040478242402, 0.000107261570787615, 
    0.00467345834692457, 0.0213892270033362, -0.0937099313495658, 
    0.00251645909947125, -0.0632956599325149, -0.00132090380066074, 
    -0.031540190910209, 0.0415217259003839, 0.0196243224662538, 
    -0.0976611527880924, 0.01713131867179, 0.0206693921571488, 
    -0.10984720875515, -0.23604335413059, -0.123298519500156, 
    0.102579391798905, -0.0619608930031467, -0.122741970750742, 
    0.107440420011137, 0.258562571065352, 0.0831288756533286, 
    0.0380738103365828, 0.102122914387041, 0.0771691647838361, 
    0.0869058388988892, -0.0542813220308744, 0.0351488706963522, 
    0.0846733840829011, -0.0167029370619785, 0.0380128870131627, 
    0.0954233112213096, 0.059146453231235, -0.0675340663722515, 
    -0.0772898672570218, -0.0756378709511565, 0.134937047612454, 
    0.0226618044495643), Q3 = c(0.0249571957657415, 0.0296065641893266, 
    0.0516467535933711, 0.0204032773069533, 0.00564130011432592, 
    0.0224283534635712, 0.00301239166268108, -0.000150963898842058, 
    0.0229134533635214, 0.0424657574061316, -0.00777680567175671, 
    -0.0445223698536066, 0.00394081997679386, 0.0240830812307228, 
    0.0124971211046563, -0.0795800732459543, -0.00881168550209076, 
    -0.0584900388668757, -0.0263079088348604, -0.0200931730088996, 
    0.0449965138077459, 0.0368462420389372, -0.114047989403222, 
    0.0267671234829322, 0.0151821869391063, -0.111191677522722, 
    -0.204383997931583, -0.126313542632778, 0.0672104859243762, 
    -0.0666682464928415, -0.0980276147276163, 0.109471163679627, 
    0.194550998802703, 0.0833334999543796, 0.0343969262838429, 
    0.0992981119758178, 0.0528223219283973, 0.0674760505087006, 
    -0.0665537698263506, 0.0342528662929908, 0.0958234167504998, 
    -0.0294131255411294, 0.0476092755160584, 0.0909138728225699, 
    0.0727903652909526, -0.0637077652670556, -0.0656483788804145, 
    -0.0551227529131964, 0.116486035743042, 0.0356988697476277
    ), Q4 = c(0.0327908558900147, -0.00581402105550901, 0.0471795087541677, 
    0.0316287353740667, 0.0154292859732494, 0.0321233577293451, 
    0.0178516903431687, 0.0297250315289144, 0.0497392455796797, 
    0.0539487711478713, 0.00185283865199054, -0.0550304813356512, 
    0.0242636750567233, 0.0215392546950305, 0.0293588232816546, 
    -0.0724868968014562, -0.000755860281788007, -0.0471606758364942, 
    -0.0207128138943517, -0.0165231425832055, 0.0434456925169798, 
    0.0391054884659545, -0.0742084088275147, 0.017590121803775, 
    0.0469003681911008, -0.096158440258061, -0.226202925207553, 
    -0.115346873402837, 0.0553655066805321, -0.0526318049432673, 
    -0.0854428438991429, 0.154789113362523, 0.20641849783792, 
    0.178990423471939, 0.0210107589738628, 0.1585673924883, 0.0698894288055367, 
    0.109538887119296, -0.0571717024643894, 0.0429703488688447, 
    0.0646785154424408, -0.0175924605503971, 0.0516479415292585, 
    0.106135927417663, 0.0894213136540906, -0.0842766439587239, 
    -0.0607679109495784, -0.064878143379156, 0.12349074462156, 
    0.0383776279423885), Q5 = c(0.0277489582011476, 0.0194428538125939, 
    0.0464771821653864, 0.0257204433555745, -0.000805859957640792, 
    0.0258752236753201, 0.00169526561907242, 0.00845686232849219, 
    0.0248138846673567, 0.0499029147276336, -0.026119026588276, 
    -0.0506759613875208, -0.0186567955284256, 0.00666071759448302, 
    0.00540296976899718, -0.0716488022451813, -0.0217757529500649, 
    -0.0338310975042987, -0.0341928029469273, -0.0223690567604255, 
    0.02094411401049, 0.0387905936222523, -0.0834270093258965, 
    0.0341064407380287, 0.00713508490452064, -0.127295832074014, 
    -0.237585142941304, -0.13633100805025, 0.0404317628621166, 
    -0.0701342930682682, -0.154994464337936, 0.137138389891867, 
    0.266473867978314, 0.149346235523739, 0.0512020926289552, 
    0.0972987430985086, 0.046678198308291, 0.0691887409841002, 
    -0.0483228606644157, 0.0438380166785084, 0.108567878481663, 
    -0.022344000031356, 0.0458931252688222, 0.0821382803979602, 
    0.0776712501269335, -0.0782288163911569, -0.0717866494829638, 
    -0.0441555801962854, 0.113855257071555, 0.0431730594966379
    ), Q6 = c(0.00118677849601953, 0.00724360975622851, 0.0123824360629239, 
    0.0142478263596263, -0.0252780297511086, -0.00458043370995016, 
    0.00425970918248347, 0.00473335833299583, 0.00103988624384509, 
    0.0228995862136097, -0.0190717885561753, -0.00298582160704901, 
    -0.025769756431826, -0.0257332343706903, 0.00216414522880129, 
    -0.00936931720546169, -0.00985230230491503, 0.00609259379175739, 
    0.00941518145826525, 0.00373315824443837, -0.00819300432209647, 
    -0.0176053121809113, 0.00728010618219631, 0.0207322622070837, 
    -0.0610342324124761, -0.0392088518323502, -0.0193263756937437, 
    0.00198527245904931, -0.00069970323347647, -0.00372528787239923, 
    -0.0155644639126446, 0.0354216053007016, 0.0671879799172312, 
    0.0600266885889786, 0.0304185023392288, 0.0153397287012177, 
    0.00380275007463411, -0.0112734150656633, 0.00937544251426276, 
    0.0172378844137663, 0.0325654123526421, 0.00585103266805692, 
    0.00344031132105193, -0.00443425955861904, 0.000415410666288515, 
    -0.00915583212652102, -0.0100144730517803, 0.0177554300128117, 
    0.0163402932978495, 0.000943194008399206), R1 = c(0.0182182283776942, 
    0.0133596019044421, 0.0432659004262889, 0.0221001061009796, 
    0.0105907624828407, 0.0239597644983188, 0.000582050596458943, 
    0.014147774983186, 0.0234533732901644, 0.0317608721171364, 
    -0.0166806564027188, -0.052434190706138, 0.0100713259540498, 
    0.0101734290645623, 0.0288354928293034, -0.0605050812338745, 
    -0.0117308063666151, -0.0572323586752662, -0.0272877553780779, 
    -0.0120147655606391, 0.0419646855503247, 0.0324565952813083, 
    -0.0993208162860145, 0.0395097806733453, 0.0238556437261408, 
    -0.114658174673633, -0.2195395447872, -0.137508094828707, 
    0.074964741726552, -0.0604685437878159, -0.111606039290815, 
    0.136833144806414, 0.222703023385423, 0.0841373058009376, 
    0.0141210132573047, 0.0945658775885383, 0.0720258311603175, 
    0.072218863181222, -0.0464783244216175, 0.0196372191978457, 
    0.0764585826402174, -0.0109085058330569, 0.0359374463515418, 
    0.0818041172339742, 0.0660486282980199, -0.0707042835229565, 
    -0.0683338724528508, -0.0610787198706517, 0.10245202132339, 
    0.0336024502788171), R2 = c(0.0191115892525381, 0.0213770552106516, 
    0.0495591080020083, 0.0217964101541805, 0.0144038778845475, 
    0.0184814835192124, 0.0105638044882981, 0.0169188201074749, 
    0.0276594408901124, 0.0348981320533056, -0.00601471285249273, 
    -0.0742367928195745, 0.00395378441574753, 0.0204693427515786, 
    0.0119432134599844, -0.0874038103063021, -0.0151874175793209, 
    -0.0472985114867765, -0.0280096128634695, -0.0160812378016462, 
    0.0321308743545342, 0.040546940059076, -0.0948356372283535, 
    0.0107826096321911, 0.0257959865133892, -0.111356276103297, 
    -0.231763659704638, -0.114593808207563, 0.0521066918649241, 
    -0.0585007082261173, -0.109123376446412, 0.126602824255329, 
    0.173736381165564, 0.199924017362175, 0.0481556947170322, 
    0.0973811981639015, 0.0359796749373038, 0.0813126198664245, 
    -0.0512295355950761, 0.0279254079344163, 0.086866979370594, 
    -0.0192548779536499, 0.0447691648075989, 0.0862634325791489, 
    0.0697143276875948, -0.0692263805833664, -0.0500105867630836, 
    -0.0588590458196327, 0.106730721635263, 0.0421188281435415
    ), R3 = c(0.0127029458612358, 0.0018533759915124, 0.0760172229180238, 
    0.0367249979117247, 0.0150598922914917, 0.0336805265497945, 
    0.00793725637078958, 0.00747404394924289, 0.0274879617237065, 
    0.043333103669918, -0.00161559239160282, -0.0455316266423957, 
    -0.00214711870702203, 0.0248726461836401, 0.00653189279270605, 
    -0.0578474430051428, -0.00753182224084245, -0.0497961950688571, 
    -0.0215957843383809, -0.0186999944968934, 0.0484307593124901, 
    0.0311984415753566, -0.0821598079518168, 0.0100672285713556, 
    0.0372802787529577, -0.104028042014104, -0.222058497109385, 
    -0.147313185333738, 0.058569009115331, -0.044662665977512, 
    -0.109997225946555, 0.0740040206123078, 0.240124115068233, 
    0.0658274676989834, 0.0230167129023561, 0.0893684046831913, 
    0.0691791022696998, 0.0935037055760548, -0.0623467636644952, 
    0.0443609426523667, 0.0841050150254741, -0.010595198663421, 
    0.0531204943650837, 0.0889886676318655, 0.0717397607923485, 
    -0.0666121329043526, -0.0679554782502061, -0.0619185083705071, 
    0.113668574986972, 0.0426805703464197), R4 = c(0.0380760367129327, 
    0.0177375553170367, 0.0434032638099822, 0.0288078728030292, 
    0.00992978596216649, 0.0292202896891021, 0.0000603359551190975, 
    0.0159922639270591, 0.0343884360605202, 0.0439464803116257, 
    -0.0138187383575441, -0.0420847227142335, -0.00232802864713809, 
    0.0234398999431073, 0.0192280943826554, -0.0652622771727051, 
    -0.0129287081223056, -0.0621169225429621, -0.0188534586231707, 
    -0.0144850139328243, 0.0297268555763311, 0.0285599283377065, 
    -0.0822735971636855, 0.0204183204990269, 0.032745768708656, 
    -0.105603577501441, -0.221743181027705, -0.13083768618741, 
    0.0451022094242408, -0.0511348958540317, -0.117597592112605, 
    0.135103916679692, 0.220409599165432, 0.123643858561056, 
    0.0412763113887445, 0.114076890036475, 0.0618001339957569, 
    0.0751807434389775, -0.0761590390584388, 0.0367453217535741, 
    0.0741501663098758, -0.0209351147382463, 0.0423510899687777, 
    0.100368821441917, 0.0695076535685885, -0.0721797128413838, 
    -0.0600897558968101, -0.0664215180686919, 0.128039957194454, 
    0.0470262161757679), R5 = c(0.0392411376774867, 0.0154176355104196, 
    0.040917916701852, 0.0218273582628919, 0.0129334794884874, 
    0.0272767829214404, 0.00362824471430165, -0.000676154777673734, 
    0.0324915392070016, 0.0312519866611661, -0.00752454226284161, 
    -0.0479068156734558, 0.00623306676125675, 0.0175638068591043, 
    0.0180622711059288, -0.0716966531562826, -0.0105557651114313, 
    -0.0470363381042701, -0.0319284024370003, -0.0274867890109039, 
    0.0328552378238075, 0.0503210109454812, -0.0847538417074522, 
    0.0213618251884607, 0.0268119067996639, -0.0900801570280097, 
    -0.229113867007717, -0.128659614134882, 0.0757805549254453, 
    -0.0540399315416828, -0.121830787213285, 0.122317733604241, 
    0.218198170804459, 0.0991190501510919, 0.0380010340764608, 
    0.119750604540555, 0.0560657704951905, 0.0599450854028368, 
    -0.0472973800122937, 0.0261746785776476, 0.0965835597718561, 
    -0.025910690013656, 0.0420420706295301, 0.101981995863621, 
    0.0648998978320577, -0.0930218340085276, -0.0682703531336771, 
    -0.0717185642128733, 0.123732482524253, 0.0358365680790375
    ), R6 = c(0.0210229092997925, 0.00205803360597752, -0.0023479837244369, 
    -0.000272747838087638, 0.00234271700564669, 0.00331701842312161, 
    0.00304619411784271, -0.0148239297608598, 0.00903816591683728, 
    -0.000508885455970276, 0.00915611413987719, 0.00452737503268219, 
    -0.00383825919279309, 0.00739037779454201, -0.0107732217233747, 
    -0.0111915719224081, 0.00117504125518384, 0.0101960205709961, 
    -0.00464064705892239, -0.0154720234502648, -0.00910944772651717, 
    0.0178644156641729, 0.0145669745785623, -0.0181479554848846, 
    0.00295626307352316, 0.024578017645623, -0.00957432222051705, 
    0.00884848069382546, 0.000815813198893262, 0.00642861224613316, 
    -0.0102247479224694, -0.0145154112021735, -0.00450485258096373, 
    0.0149817443501543, 0.0238800208191561, 0.0251847269520169, 
    -0.015960060665127, -0.0122737777783852, -0.000819055590676188, 
    0.00653745937980193, 0.0201249771316388, -0.0150021841805991, 
    0.0061046242779883, 0.020177878629647, -0.00114873046596223, 
    -0.0223175504855711, 0.0000635193191737132, -0.0106398443422216, 
    0.0212804612008627, 0.00223411780022038)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `dput` will not produce reproducible output if there are internal pointers in the object being output.  Convert `rets` to a data frame and `dput` that.

Comment: `"X6" is calculated as "X5 - X1"` - this is the reason you can't inverse the cov matrix. Since one of the columns is a linear combination of the others, the rank of the matrix is less than the number of columns.

Comment: Another way to see this is that, since some of the columns are a linear combination of others, the determinant of `cov` is zero. If a determinant of a matrix is zero, it is not possible to obtain its inverse.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I have updates the dataframe `rets`. So what you are saying is that I cannot continue with this type of procedure (i.e. including X6)? I was hoping to perform some further analysis with the "X6" variables but if I have to omit this step its not the worst part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, nothing in the question has anything to do with lpSolve or with `retbar` so please remove this junk from the question.

`covs` is singular so it cannot be inverted.  Note the essentially zero eigenvalues below. Evidently the columns that are linearly dependent on the remaining columns are those set to NULL so removing them eliminates the singularity.  If a Moore-Penrose generalized inverse is sufficient then `MASS::ginv(covs)` could be used.

```
covs <- var(rets, na.rm = TRUE)
eigen(covs)$values
```

giving the following eigenvector which includes 4 near zeros:

```
 [1]  1.147251e-01  4.508339e-03  3.566784e-03  9.437460e-04  6.489510e-04
 [6]  4.975564e-04  3.300602e-04  2.840001e-04  2.674243e-04  2.202487e-04
[11]  1.428033e-04  9.985863e-05  9.513909e-05  7.955750e-05  6.892488e-05
[16]  5.715785e-05  4.055359e-05  3.127846e-05  2.710167e-05  6.273551e-06
[21]  6.322894e-19  2.240421e-19 -3.041137e-19 -9.827006e-19
```